# CSS Menu drop-down alignment issue

Tags: css

I'm working on a site for my client and the menu is bothering me too much as the drop-down is not getting perfectly aligned in different widths and browsers. I used hacks and CSSuseragent but still there remains an issue of a pixel or two.

Check website here – http://www.drearth.in

---

```
CSS Code:

    @charset "UTF-8";
nav {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.menu-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu {
    width: 925px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-image: url(../images/line-0.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 40px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 46px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.table {
    display: table; /* Allow the centering to work */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    /* [disabled]float: left; */
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.menu li {
    font-family: 'AkzidenzGroteskBE-Md', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #d6d3cd;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.menu>li {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    /* [disabled]margin-top: 50px; */
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.bud {
    display: block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 12px;
    background-image: url(../images/bud.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.menu li a {
    color: #d6d3cd;
    position: relative;
    /* [disabled]float: left; */
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 23px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 21px;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu li:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/line-1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
.menu li:hover > a {
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #AECF43;
    background-image: url(../images/line-1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}
.menu li .visit {
    color: #AECF43;
}
ul.menu-hover {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 10000;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.menu li:hover .menu-hover {
    visibility: visible;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: none;
}
.menu-hover li {
    height: 100%;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    background-color: #00000D;
    border-right-color: #586922;
    border-left-color: #586922;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    background-image: url(../images/line-2.jpg);
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: 0px;
}
.menu-hover li:hover > a {
    letter-spacing: normal;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    background-image: none;
}
.menu-hover li:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/line-2.jpg);
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.menu-hover li a {
    color: #d6d3cd;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:'AkzidenzGroteskBE-Cn', "Arial Narrow Bold", "Arial Narrow", "Arial", sans-serif !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    /* [disabled]float: left; */
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    background-image: none;
    line-height: 43px;
}
.menu a span:after {
    content: "";
    /* [disabled]border-left: 3px solid transparent; */
    /* [disabled]border-right: 3px solid transparent; */
    /* [disabled]border-bottom: 3px solid #A5A5A5; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 47%;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
.menu li:hover span:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* [disabled]border-left: 3px solid transparent; */
    /* [disabled]border-right: 3px solid transparent; */
    /* [disabled]border-bottom: 3px solid #A5A5A5; */
}
.menu-hover li:first-child{
    border-radius: 0;
}
.menu-hover li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #586922;
    background-image: none;
}
.menu-hover li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    background-image: none;
}
.menu-hover a:after {
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
}
#link1  {
    width: 189px;
}
#link2 {
    width: 131px;
}
#link3 {
    width: 166px;
}
#link4 {
    width: 110px;
}
#link5 {
    width: 134px;
}
#link6 {
    width: 97px;
}
#link7 {
}


/* Firefox Hack */
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
 .menu li {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
 .menu-hover li a {
    font-size: 13px !important;
}
 #link1 {
    width: 186px; !important;
}
 #link2 {
    width: 128px; !important;
}
 #link3 {
    width: 162px; !important;
}
 #link4 {
    width: 109px; !important;
}
 #link5 {
    width: 131px; !important;
}
 #link6 {
    width: 95px; !important;
}
}

.ua-opera #link1 {
    width: 189px;
}
.ua-opera #link2 {
    width: 131px;
}
.ua-opera #link5 {
    width: 135px;
}
.ua-opera #link6 {
    width: 96px;
}


.ua-safari .menu li {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.ua-safari #link1 {
    width: 190px;
}
.ua-safari #link2 {
    width: 131px;
}
.ua-safari #link3 {
    width: 165px;
}
.ua-safari #link4 {
    width: 111px;
}
.ua-safari #link5 {
    width: 135px;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

BK Suru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your width definitions on .link1, it looks fine in Chrome. Moreover in this way you dont have to use reduntant classes like now. (.link1, .link2 etc)

The definition:

```
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

The `box-sizing` fix needs because of the 2x 1px border.

Chenk out:

[image]

Comment: Thanks DNRenTi, but that's only a temporary solution and works at a certain width. At lower resolution it mis-aligns again.

Comment: Here is the fix, apply these definitions on your .link# classes:
`width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;`
It works fine in Chrome, on any resolution. ;) I edit my original answer.

Comment: Hey buddy.... that's an awesome fix man... thanks a lot buddy... you're a rockstar bro!

Comment: All because of you mate :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please add right:0 and left: 0 on .ul.menu-hover this class. and 
.menu-hover li {width:100%} I think it will work fine

Comment: Hey Kumar... Nope... right:0 or right:0 !important doesn't work.

I think it's an issue with font rendering or width/padding that is getting disturbed when the width changes. Any clues?

Comment: add .menu-hover li: 100% too

Comment: Hey Kumar, thanks! What it has done now is fixed both drop-downs but is slightly off towards the right by 2px. I have also removed the custom hacks, which seem somewhat less useful now but as long as the above solution takes care of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kumar for helping out :-)